# Uniqueness of positional computation system

Tags: analysis, real-numbers

I was reading Mathematical Analysis by Zorich and was confused by one of his statements.

Zorich used the principle of Archimedes to construct a sequence of rational                 numbers to approximate $x$:
$$
r_n\leqslant x<r_n+\frac{1}{q^{n-p}},\qquad (2.8)
$$
where
$$
r_n=\alpha _pq^p+\alpha _{p-1}q^{p-1}+\cdots +\alpha _{p-n}q^{p-n}
$$
where $\alpha_i$ are digits.

On page 63 Zorich wrote

> It can be seen by inequalities (2.8) (verify this!) that different sequences $\left\{r_{n}\right\}$ and $\left\{r_{n}^{\prime}\right\},$ and therefore different symbols $\alpha_{p} \ldots \alpha_{0} \ldots$ and $\alpha_{p}^{\prime} \ldots \alpha_{0}^{\prime} \ldots,$ correspond to
>   different numbers $x$ and $x'$.

I am confused by the use of "inequalities" stated in this paragraph. From my point of view, since the sequence is constructed by the principle of Archimedes, the numbers $\alpha _i$ should be unique and thus there is no need to use inequalities. Is my thought correct or does this statement need to be proved by inequalities?

Many thanks.

Comment: I _think_ the inequality is precisely what tells you the $\alpha$'s are unique. It's the assertion in the division with remainder lemma that says that the remainder is less than what you are dividing by.

Comment: Do you mean that this is exactly the uniqueness from the principle of Archimedes? His statement is a little bit confusing((

Comment: Archimedes doesn't specify uniqueness. That requires extra argument. I haven't read the question carefully, which is why I posted my observation as a comment rather than an answer. I do think it's a confusing way to establish positional notation.